# unable to evaluate the expression in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to evaluate the following:

```
a= 08
b= 5
echo `expr $a + $b`
```

It gives the error: `"Couldn't evaluate expression operands as numeric as required by the expression operator."`

It seems there is problem with 08. It is not treating it as 8.

Thanks in advance,
Milind

Answer (score 0):

The leading `0` in `08` denotes an *octal literal*, and `8` is not a valid octal digit.

Comment: Drop the leading zero?

Comment: I have three values 00:01:08 , 00:01:18 & 00:01:11
this is time stamp & I want to convert it to seconds so I am assigning hh mm ss values to three variable & using conversion formula (hh*3600 + mm*60 +ss) trying to solve this. I cant eliminate 08 in first value